# Crossbar.io close router when guest worker is down

Tags: python, wamp, autobahn, crossbar

I am playing with crossbar.io for quite a while and I faced with some sync issue.
Problem:
I'm running my python backend as guest worker and wants to exit router when that python guest worker is down. I've set controller.options.shutdown for "shoutdown_on_worker_exit" but seems to have no effect if just python process is killed.
How can I get crossbar.io exit after the python guest process kill?

Guest process config:

```
{
    "type": "guest",
    "executable": "python3",
    "arguments": ["../backend/backend.py"],
    "options": {
    }
}
```

Controller config:

```
"controller": {
    "id": "mynode1",
    "options": {
        "title": "mainController",
        "shutdown": ["shutdown_on_worker_exit"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run this worker in/with container. Following [this](https://crossbar.io/docs/Container-Configuration/) and [this](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar-examples/blob/master/sharedregs/python/.crossbar/config.json)